# Can't make successful deploy to Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using the **eb** CLI to deploy my RoR API to Beanstalk, and although the deploy works, the app **degrated**. I can see that it fails with:

```
+ bundle install
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:284:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.1.4) required by your /var/app/ondeck/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.1.4`
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `activate_bin_path'
from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'.
```

I'm not finding in the AWS docs what I should do to fix this and prevent from happening again. Has anyone experienced the same, or knows why it's happening, and more important, how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

The bundler version of your elastic beanstalk is not 2.1.4 which is required by your project. Add an elastic beanstalk config file to upgrade the pre-installed bundler of elastic beanstalk.

```
#.ebextensions/bundler_update.config

commands:
  update_bundler:
    command: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/bin/gem install bundler -v 2.1.4
```

Ruby and Bundler version should match yours.